# Angular not showing errors properly

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

In my angular app, it does not show errors properly. It always shows errors in main.js instead of component and line number like it shows on my other angular applications. Please check this screenshot[image: error]

Here is my angular.json. It looks like it's missing development configuration.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "fadcd178-4e22-400b-975d-788758cb58bf"
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "route-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/route-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
              "node_modules/leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css",
              "src/app/themes/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "2mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "5kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "route-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "route-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "route-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "../node_modules/ngx-simple-modal/styles/simple-modal.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "route-app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "route-app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "route-app"
}
```

and here is my packages.json

```
{
  "name": "route-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    
  }
}
```

Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add development configuration like this.

```
        "build": {
             :
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
               :
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          }
        }
        "serve": {
            :
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "route-app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "route-app:build:development"
            }
          }
```

Then start your app with `ng serve -c development`.

Comment: can you elaborate, please? I use ng serve to serve the app in my browser

Comment: getting error 

 ng serve -c development
An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'development' is not set in the workspace.
See "/private/var/folders/rj/bq0ld78s20vbn0plbbwv029h0000gn/T/ng-rw0K0z/angular-errors.log" for further details.

Comment: Sorry I have missed to update configuration file. You have to add it to `serve` section. I again updated my answer.

Comment: Can you exactly tell me which parameter enables the error logging in the development configuration?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration in the angular.json file should enable the source map for the environment you are working with, for instance, to map the errors in the "dev" environment:

```
configuration:{
     ...,        
    "dev":{ 
        ...,    
        "sourceMap": true,
        ...
    },
    ...,
}
```

Without the "sourceMap" : true, the error will not be traced to the specific source file. This parameter can be assigned a boolean or an object, but "true" should be enough to solve your problem, as descibed in the official documentation:

https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#source-map-configuration